# Critique - Logo design for baby-related products

Tags: logo, critique

I am launching an e-commerce brand targeted to parents of newborn babies. The products I am starting with are teething necklaces and teething rattlers. The products are meant to be a stylish piece of jewelery accessory worn by the mom but can be used as a teething toy for a baby.

FEEDBACK QUESTIONS:

- I would like to know if the logo represents my vision of products or is it too focused on the nurturing portion (baby representation design)?
- I am interested in knowing if the ratio of the vector logo portion, vs the brand name, seems correct or should I change the ratio to offer more of the name or of the vector logo?
- What would you suggest the layout to be when making a rectangular tag? 
  I am having a hard time liking my rectangular layout of the logo.
- Any additional feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just personal opinion....

- The eyes/mouth of the clouds should possibly be the same stroke weight as their outer stroke and *possibly* the same color as well - things I would explore.
- I detest the type. You aren't "marketing to babies". Babies don't *buy* anything. You are marketing to mothers (and maybe fathers). The childlike type is, I understand, common in such markets. However, I feel that in itself makes it a tad cliché. But again, I realize it's kind of used as a "category identifier" to some degree and it may just be that it's not "my style". In any event..
- Matching the line weight of the type with the clouds would balance things visually a bit more perhaps.
- The leading on the "tag" between "tiny" and "Clouds" seems a bit too large.
- I would reduce the size of the clouds by about 80% in the circle version. I think sizing is good for the "tag".

**Overall, I'd add..**. if you were to ask 100 designers for a ["mother, baby" logo](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1124&bih=1062&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=9sXpW4OhCYPL_QbEsK-wDQ&q=mother%20baby%20logo&oq=mother%20baby%20logo&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i7i30l4j0i7i5i30j0i8i30l3.16021.16778..16990...0.0..0.126.866.0j7......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i8i7i30.cTYUJM3bsDw) ... I imagine at least 50% of the logos which returned would use pink as the primary color and some form of "baby scrawl" for type. .... just pointing that out. These two aspects **work directly against** being a *"unique identifier"* in the marketplace.

There's no rule which states mothers prefer pink... or that baby products *must* use chicken scratch for type. I just thank the powers that be you didn't reverse the `y` or `s` to further promote that an infant made the type.

I apologize if this comes across a bit harsh. It's been said that my answers don't always *seem* friendly. I assure you though I mean everything honestly and in a absolutely friendly manner as if I were speaking to a colleague and as a way to *help* if possible. Just imagine my answer littered with smileys and grins `:)`.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for your feedback. I will take them into consideration and create some variations of the vector file to see the appeal of it.

Comment: +1 for You aren't "marketing to babies". Being a parent myself I ab-so-lutely hate this.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely see a bit of a disconnection between the logo and the product itself. I think a good way to reconsider designing the logo is to first design a logo that would only work for a women's jewelry company (no nurturing elements), and then try to find a happy medium between that logo and the more child-friendly logo you designed.

Just from googling "Jewelry Logo" I noticed a wider selection of refined logos tailored to the female audience - it would be worth researching more in depth to consider adding finer lines and *much* more structured details.

I think one of the bigger issues with the logo is that it's simply far too gestural and loose with both the typography and the cloud icons, which makes the logo hard to take seriously.

To include more subtle, thinner line weights (as was mentioned in another comment) would likely be enough to refine the logo more.

I'm not entirely sure about the "Tiny Clouds" name either, in that it also seems to lean more on the child as a target audience than the mother as a purchaser of the product. But perhaps this is also because "Tiny Clouds" is written with a very playful font. In either case, I would consider doing a few sketches to create a logo that could include a few pieces of the necklace itself (a few blue dots for example). It's a bit too literal to have a logo name and then an icon that reiterates what the name said.

Hope this is helpful, but please let me know of any points to elaborate on.

Comment: It's definetely too focused on the nurturing portion. I think you have to find a way to combine baby with elegant or funky. As was mentioned previously the logo focuses only on baby and not at all on mom or jewellery. You might want too make it more colorful as well.

Comment: Awesome feedback Reine.

Answer (score 0):

First the positive: The illustration is cute, and appropriate for the concept and target market. I like it. Like it's been mentioned, perhaps making the strokes for the eyes/mouth thicker would work.

The first layout works well, except the double line on the outside is a bit distracting. The second one is not so good, the sizing is off( the "baby" text is tiny). Perhaps try:

Tiny Clouds

Baby (cloud illustration)

The type: I get what you're going for with the kid-like type, but if you want sophistication, you should rethink this font. Even if you decide on the hand-drawn look, there are nicer fonts than this one to choose from.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Spiral. I appreciate it.